how to Get all token that are subscribed to particular topic
I want to know if Firebase provides a way to directly retrieve a list of all device tokens subscribed to a specific topic without using a database to store that information. Specifically, I would like to be able to give a topic name and receive a list of all connected device tokens that are subscribed to that topic. Does Firebase offer such functionality?
I want to retrieve a list of all device tokens that are subscribed to a specific topic directly from Firebase, without using a database to store or manage that information. Does Firebase offer a feature that allows you to provide a topic name and receive a list of all the connected device tokens?
